# Is it possible to login with Firebase and REST API at the same time?

Tags: firebase, api, rest, authentication, jwt

I have a mobile app that does two things. The first one is to use Firebase to implement a chat. On the other side, the apps, uses a REST API to retrieve some info from a database and do some writes on it. Simple as that. The app provides a login system: two text fields and a button. The user provides an email address and a password then I used the standard Firebase function to do the login using `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`. The thing is that I should use the same credentials to do the login using the REST API to access the other database. At first I decided to do the call to Firebase and to the REST API in the same function. One other possible solution could be a web service. I'll explain how. A web services written in Python, PHP or JavaScript generates a JWT token that is sent to the mobile app after the user asks to sign in. I'm pretty sure that this is possible like shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin. The latter seems too over-complicated to me. Now, the question is. Can someone suggest a solution, the most simple one, that can be used is a scenario like this? Thanks all in advance.

Comment: From what I understand, you use Firebase Authentication and also have your own auth system? To simplify this, you can just use Firebase Auth to sign in users and then use Firebase's ID Tokens to [verify the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) on your own server. Is that possible to do in your use case?

Comment: Yes, it is. Tnx